# In which order does a node select peers to create a connection?

Tags: network, connection

In the function `connections_maker` in `net_node.inl` a node selects the peers to which it tries to create a connection. [This](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/5fbfa8a65663e807c6500ae9485e898df9b7c470/src/p2p/net_node.inl#L1391) computation seems to be important in which order we select the peers: either from anchor list, white list and grey list or from grey list and white list. However, I have some troubles to figure out when we select which order. Can anybody explain that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does a node maintain its anchor peer list?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/11113/how-does-a-node-maintain-its-anchor-peer-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anchor first, then white, then gray.

Comment: Yes, I agree. But there is an `else` branch: grey list and then white list. My question is when do we take this `else` branch?

Comment: That else branch is hit if we have exhausted our expected white connection count, so it then tries some grays. If we specified we wanted to maintain a total of 10 outgoing peers, and of those, we wanted to say try 3 whites, once we have 3 whites connected, then try the grays.